# Managing Layouts in MigLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout

The following code creates a `JFrame` with a `JTextField array` in it. It also creates a `JMenuBar` at the top which allows you to select how many `JTextFields` you want to display (1-20) and then uses various layouts to display them on the `JPanel`.

I'm looking mainly for comments/thoughts on how the program lays out the `JTextField`s. Could this be done quicker or easier?

**StitchSorts**

```
import GUIMain.*;

public class StitchSorts
{   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        StitchSorts sS = new StitchSorts();
        SortsGui.main(args);
    }
}
```

**SortsGui**

```
package GUIMain;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class SortsGui
{
    JFrame myMainWindow = new JFrame("Sorts");

    JPanel sortPanel = new JPanel();

    public int nextTextBox = 10;
    JTextField[] allField = new JTextField [20];

    public void runGUI()
    {
        myMainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        myMainWindow.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));

        createSortTestPanel();

        MyMenuBar mbr = new MyMenuBar(this);

        myMainWindow.setJMenuBar(mbr);

        myMainWindow.getContentPane().add(sortPanel);

        myMainWindow.setVisible(true);

        myMainWindow.pack();

        myMainWindow.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(myMainWindow.getBounds().getSize()));
    }

    public void createSortTestPanel()
    {
        MigLayout layout = new MigLayout("" , "[grow]");
        sortPanel.setLayout(layout);

        refreshScreen();
    }

    public void refreshScreen()
    {
        sortPanel.removeAll();

        MigLayout layout = new MigLayout("", "[grow]");
        if(nextTextBox<12)
        {
            layout = new MigLayout("", "[grow]");
        }
        else if(nextTextBox>11)
        {
            layout = new MigLayout("wrap 1", "[grow]");
        }

        sortPanel.setLayout(layout);

        for(int i = 0; i<nextTextBox;i++)
        {
            int fix = i+1;
            allField[i] = new JTextField("");

            if(nextTextBox<12)
            {
                sortPanel.add(allField[i],"growx, width 100:100:");
            }

            else if(nextTextBox==12)
            {
                sortPanel.add(allField[i],"growx, width 100:100:, split 6");
            }

            else if(nextTextBox==13)
            {
                if(fix<8)
                {
                    sortPanel.add(allField[i],"growx, width 100:100:, split 7");
                }
                else
                {
                    sortPanel.add(allField[i],"growx, width 100:100:, split 6");
                }
            }

            else if(nextTextBox==14)
            {
                sortPanel.add(allField[i],"growx, width 100:100:, split 7");
            }

            else if(nextTextBox==15)
            {
                if(fix<9)
                {
                    sortPanel.add(allField[i],"growx, width 100:100:, split 8");
                }
                else
                {
                    sortPanel.add(allField[i],"growx, width 100:100:, split 7");
                }
            }

            else if(nextTextBox==16)
            {
                sortPanel.add(allField[i],"growx, width 100:100:, split 8");
            }

            else if(nextTextBox==17)
            {
                if(fix<10)
                {
                    sortPanel.add(allField[i],"growx, width 100:100:, split 9");
                }
                else
                {
                    sortPanel.add(allField[i],"growx, width 100:100:, split 8");
                }
            }

            else if(nextTextBox==18)
            {
                sortPanel.add(allField[i],"growx, width 100:100:, split 9");
            }

            else if(nextTextBox==19)
            {
                if(fix<11)
                {
                    sortPanel.add(allField[i],"growx, width 100:100:, split 10");
                }
                else
                {
                    sortPanel.add(allField[i],"growx, width 100:100:, split 9");
                }
            }

            else if(nextTextBox==20)
            {
                sortPanel.add(allField[i],"growx, width 100:100:, split 10");
            }
        }

        myMainWindow.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(0,0));
        myMainWindow.pack();
        Dimension dD = new Dimension(myMainWindow.getBounds().getSize());
        myMainWindow.setMinimumSize(dD);
        sortPanel.repaint();
        sortPanel.validate();
        myMainWindow.repaint();
        myMainWindow.validate();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SortsGui sG = new SortsGui();
        sG.runGUI();
    }
}
```

**MyMenuBar**

```
package GUIMain;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class MyMenuBar extends JMenuBar
{
    int fontMetrics;
    FontMetrics fM;
    String lblSortsString = "Select amount of JTextFields to display";

    String sortsArray[]={"01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20"};
    JComboBox sortComboBox = new JComboBox(sortsArray);

    JLabel lblSorts = new JLabel(lblSortsString, SwingConstants.CENTER);

    SortsGui sG;

    public MyMenuBar(SortsGui sG)
    {
        this.sG = sG;
        setBorderPainted(true);
        makePopUpMenu();
    }

    void makePopUpMenu()
    {
        fM = lblSorts.getFontMetrics(lblSorts.getFont());
        fontMetrics = fM.stringWidth(lblSortsString);
        lblSorts.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(fontMetrics+10,25));
        lblSorts.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(fontMetrics+10,25));
        lblSorts.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(fontMetrics+10,25));
        add(lblSorts);

        sortComboBox.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(60,25));
        sortComboBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60,25));
        sortComboBox.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(60,25));
        sortComboBox.addItemListener(new sortComboBoxChanged());
        sortComboBox.setFocusable(false);
        add(sortComboBox);
        sortComboBox.setSelectedItem("10");
    }

    class sortComboBoxChanged implements ItemListener
    {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
        {
            String s = sortComboBox.getSelectedItem()+"";
            sG.nextTextBox = Integer.parseInt(s);
            sG.refreshScreen();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm looking mainly for comments/thoughts on how the program lays out the JTextFields. Could this be done quicker or easier?

If you're talking about the lots of `if (nextTextBox == ?)` and `if (fix < ?)`, I have a few things in mind:

1. Creating custom graphical layouts is often full of details with no general logic. Very often there is no escape from large blocks of code setting layout details, or complicated if-else branches
2. On closer look, between `nextTextBox==12` and `nextTextBox==20`, I see a pattern that can be generated using a formula. It might be worth rewriting it that way, especially if you intend to add more text boxes that would follow the same logic
3. The common string part "growx, width 100:100:, split " should definitely be in a variable, rather than duplicated so many times

#### Naming issues

`sS`, `sG`, `dD`, `fL` are terrible names.
Try to find better names that describe what these variables represent.

Instead of `allField`, `allFields` (plural) would be more natural for an array (also considering the "all" prefix).

#### Style issues

The placement of braces doesn't follow common Java practices.
It's also recommended to put spaces around operators.
For example, instead of this:

> ```
>     for(int i = 0; i<nextTextBox;i++)
>     {
>         int fix = i+1;
>         allField[i] = new JTextField("");
>
>         if(nextTextBox<12)
>         {
>             sortPanel.add(allField[i],"growx, width 100:100:");
>         }
> ```

The recommended writing style:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < nextTextBox; i++) {
        int fix = i + 1;
        allField[i] = new JTextField("");

        if (nextTextBox < 12) {
            sortPanel.add(allField[i], "growx, width 100:100:");
        }
```